# Convert internal web application to public web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been tasked with setting up an internal web application to become public facing. The web site was written in ASP.Net and I am just looking for some advice about how I should go about this procedure.

Apart from hosting the site on a public facing server I don't know what else I would need to take into consideration.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [ASP.NET Web Application Project Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx)

and this one also helps [HOW TO: Deploy an ASP.NET Web Application Using the Copy Project Feature in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326356)

Comment: That first article looks to be exactly what I am searching for. Thanks very much!